# Firebase Function Get Single Value From Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to get a single value from Firebase Database within Firebase function. However, the Promise never returns and the chained method never executes. Here is the method that fetches a value from the database

```
function getFcmToken(username){
    return admin.database().ref('tokens/{username}/fcmToken').once('value').then(snap => {
        if(snap.exists()){
            const token = Object.keys(snap.val());
            console.log("FCM Token", token);
            return token;
        }
        return [];
    });
}
```

The above method was supposed to return a token, but I am not sure it is, so the method below does not get executed.

```
function sendNotification(keyword, username){
    return getFcmToken(username).then(token => {
        if(token.length > 0){
            //Notification Detail
            let payload = {
                data:{
                   keyword: keyword 
                }
            };
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
        }
    });
}
```

In the console log, all I see is Promise pending.

How can I update the code above to return a single value, it appears it is returning an array?

Thanks

Comment: is your ref path correct?

Comment: yes, the path is correct, I verified. I have another function that writes to that path correctly

Comment: I mean username is replaced in single quotes? I doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database ref path is wrong. You might wanted to replace username in path, but single quoted won't do that.

Firebase is listening on `tokens/{username}/fcmToken`, which doesn't exists. Hence on value event will not be triggered and so downline callback will not be executed.

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for building dynamic strings.

Try ref path as

```
`tokens/${username}/fcmToken`
```

Code:

```
function getFcmToken(username){
    return admin.database().ref(`tokens/${username}/fcmToken`).once(...)     

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure that is the problem if I add the $ as you suggested, then the function will with the following error Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "tokens/${username}/fcmToken". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
    at Error (native)

Comment: Did you used backtick or quotes? Try printing path in console. You must user `backtick` to replace variables in strings

Comment: @PriyeshKumar  hey, I want to send the username with the body of notify and here is what it save in my DB like this https://imgur.com/65Z25Rh , and i save it a variable like this `const userName = snapshot.after.val().username._55` but the logs tell me **Cannot read property '_55' of undefined at exports.sendPushR.functions.database.ref.onWrite**